# Radio button getting selected value jquery with Uploadify

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is my code . what i am getting is always 'no' even if i select 'yes'
This is my html code . while testing in firebug console it works fine .  i have tried .each function as well but its still getting no value .Some times it takes right value of check box but it continues taking that value then several times

```
           <form  >
            <table width="900" cellpadding="5" border="0" >


              <tr>
                 <td width="30"><input type="radio"  class="radio_bg" name="profile_rpt_bg"    value="yes"></td>
                 <td>Repeat Background</td>
           </tr>

       <tr class="graybackgroundlight">
        <td><input   type="radio" name="profile_rpt_bg" class="radio_bg"   checked="checked"   value="no"></td>
         <td>Do not Repeat Background</td>
       </tr>
         </table>

       </form>
```

This is my javascript code

```
          $(document).ready(function(){


    $('#file_upload_bg').uploadify({
     'formData'      : {

         'artist_id' : '<?php echo $artist_details['id']; ?>',
      'username' : '<?php echo $artist_details['username'];?>',
      'rpt': $("input[name='profile_rpt_bg']:checked").val(),
      'column' : 'profile_bg'


      },
     'auto'          : false,
     'multi'         : false,   
     'fileTypeDesc'  : 'Image Files',
     'fileTypeExts'  : '*.jpg; *.png',
     'swf'           : 'uploadify.swf',
     'uploader'      : 'artist_uploadify.php' ,

      'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) 


      {
          alert(data);

        $("#container").notify("create", {
        title: 'Success',
        text: file.name+' Uploaded with success'
         });      







      }
      // Your options here

    }); //uploadify ends


    });
```

Comment: I think you can take the value directly `$("input[name='profile_rpt_bg']").val()` without `:checked`

Comment: not working the problem i think is its taking value of radio button at start  but on change its not changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it .....

```
              'onUploadStart' : function(file) 
              {
                     $('#file_upload_bg').uploadify("settings", "formData", {"rpt":    $("input[name='profile_rpt_bg']:checked").val()});
              },
```

adding this in uploadify

actually it was uploadify plugin problem not jquery ..

Thanks any ways

Answer (score 0):

Check this its working fine in this fiddle...

```
$('input[name=profile_rpt_bg]').on('click', function() {
    alert( $('input[name=profile_rpt_bg]:checked').val() );
});​
```

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvbzj/1/)**